# Regular expression error when using stringr (R package) to search for curly brackets

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to search for curly brackets in text strings in R, using the stringr package. Using the following code:

```
library(stringr)
textstring <- 'abc}defg}hij'
str_locate_all(textstring, 'e')
```

works fine, but

```
str_locate_all(textstring, '}')
```

gives the following error message:

> Error in stri_locate_all_regex(string, pattern, omit_no_match = TRUE, 
>   :    Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)

I am using R version 3.2.1 and stringr version 1.0.0 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Either escape the metacharacter or place it in a bracketed expression, otherwise you can just do `str_locate_all(textstring, fixed('}'))`

Comment: I had the same issue with `str_split_fixed` and `?`, the `fixed("?")` works perfectly ; thanks a lot @hwnd

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`{` is a special character - you have to escape it:

```
str_locate_all(textstring, '\\}')
```

Comment: Problem solved, thank you! I tried to escape it with one backslash (which did not work), but the double backslash does the trick.

Comment: I had the same error. In my case, I use `'\\+'` in `str_count` function as recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the clue and done like follows to replace all the + from spaces:

```
str_replace_all(df$Installs, "\\+", " ")
```