# String remove up to last "}"

Tags: r, regex, rvest, data-wrangling

Rvest output is inserting a long string of extra data in one of the cells:

```
QC1 <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_Quebec")%>% 
  html_node('body #content #bodyContent #mw-content-text .mw-parser-output table') %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```

QC1$Coordinates first cell starts with:
.mw-parser-output .geo-default,.mw-parser-output .geo-dms,.mw-parser-output .geo-dec{display:inline}.mw-parser-output .geo-nondefault,.mw-parser-output .geo-multi-punct{display:none}.mw-parser-output .longitude,.mw-parser-output .latitude{white-space:nowrap}60°49′07″N 078°08′55″W﻿ / ﻿60.81861°N 78.14861°W﻿ / 60.81861; -78.14861﻿ (Akulivik Airport)

and all other cells start with the numeric coordinate data. I have tried str_remove but I find the fruit-based examples in the documentation limited and unhelpful when dealing with more complicated regex than "banana".

I'd like to delete everything from that first Coordinate cell until the LAST "}". I thought I could add a pipe with `str_remove(., "^.*}")` or gsub but it hasn't worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should use `str_remove(., "(?s)^.*}")` if there are line breaks before the last `}`. You also might use ``str_extract(., "[^}]+$")``

Comment: I have just tried and `QC1$Coordinates <- sub(".*}", "", QC1$Coordinates)` works.

Comment: `str_remove` suggestion was throwing an error because the curly bracket needed to be escaped. I've added your solution to the rewrite of `str_remove`

Comment: I have updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67728957/3832970) with explanation and alternative solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(textreadr)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

QC1 <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_Quebec")%>% 
   html_node('body #content #bodyContent #mw-content-text .mw-parser-output table') %>% 
   html_table(fill = TRUE) 

QC1$Coordinates <- sub(".*}", "", QC1$Coordinates)
```

The first item will look as expected:

```r
> QC1$Coordinates[1]
[1] "60°49′07″N 078°08′55″W / 60.81861°N 78.14861°W / 60.81861; -78.14861 (Akulivik Airport)"
```

The `sub(".*}", "", QC1$Coordinates)` code line removes all text up to the last `}` including the char.

**NOTE**: The regex engine  used by `sub`/`gsub` by defaul is TRE, and this regex engine does not require a `}` char to be escaped, it is not a special regex metacharacter there. However, `str_remove` requires `}` to be escaped because the regex engine used in `stringr`/`stringi` functions is ICU, and this regex engine is rather different from both TRE and PCRE commonly used in `gsub`/`sub`, etc. base R functions.

So, you can also use

```r
str_remove(., "^.*\\}")
str_remove(., "(?s)^.*\\}") ## If there are line breaks before last }
str_remove(., "^.*[}]")     ## Inside brackets, } is not special
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting `Error in stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  :  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)` 
because } [is a special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585111/regular-expression-error-when-using-stringr-r-package-to-search-for-curly-brac) (thanks to [LukeA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1327739/lukea))

So `QC1$Coordinates %<>% str_remove(., pattern="^.*\\}")` or `QC1$Coordinates  %<>%  sub(".*}", "", .)` are functionally equivalent (thanks to [Wiktor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) for the alternative). Seems `sub()` doesn't freak out with `}` for some reason.